# applyformat in gutenberg doesnt work and no errors

Tags: block-editor

I am trying to apply a format to the selected text, but the apply format method of gutenberg doesnt return any error and fails silently.

I am registering my format type like this

```
import { registerFormatType } from "@wordpress/rich-text";

registerFormatType(BLOCK_NAME, {
          title: "Answer",
          tagName: "span",
          className: SOME_CLASS
        });
```

and trying to apply like this

```
    on(SOME_EVENT, result => {
    applyFormat(props.value, { type: BLOCK_NAME });
}
```

The applyformat method doesn't throw any errors but when i try to apply the format to the text selection it didnt create the  wrapper around it.It fails silently, any reason why its not working?

**Update:**
I did a console.log on result from apply format, but it didnt return the formatted text.

```
const result = applyFormat(props.value, { type: BLOCK_NAME });
console.log(result)
```

props.value in console

```
{formats: Array(16), text: "qwe qwewq eqweq?", start: 4, end: 11}
```

value of result from applyFormat

```
{formats: Array(16), text: "qwe qwewq eqweq?", start: 4, end: 11}
```

I expect the applyFormat to add a span with a class name around the selected text, what am i doing wrong in the code?

Comment: Can you expand your code snippets to include more? It's unclear how/where you're calling `applyFormat`. By trying to hide what you're doing you've made it too generic

Comment: @TomJNowell I am calling it inside a event handler, which i can assure getting triggered ( i didnt hide it intentionally, i just wanted to provide a mwe (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), i am adding some data again to the post.

Comment: @TomJNowell added some more details to the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after 5 hrs i have learnt this, you need to call applyFormat inside the props.onChange method, so the code would look like this

```
props.onChange( applyFormat(props.value, { type: BLOCK_NAME }) );
```

if you didnt execute the applyformat inside this props.onChange, no error would be thrown, but it would fail silently.

Answer (score 0):

You won't see applied format in result's `text` attribute, however your result should have new `activeFormats` attribute. To get HTML with applied formats you can use `wp.richText.toHTMLString({result})`. [This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325524/using-applyformat-from-wordpress-rich-text-to-make-persistent-changes-to-gute) might help with some ideas.